# Incorrect file specified, please check your path. - FlexPaper

Tags: flash, flexpaper

I installed SWFTools using the following commands

```
wget http://swftools.org/swftools-0.9.0.tar.gz
tar -zvxf swftools-0.9.0.tar.gz
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

and configured `SWFTools` to flexpaper via setting the installed location `/usr/local/bin`

but after I am unloading the PDF it's throwing me an error

```
"Incorrect file specified, please check your path." I can see pdf.swf files are not getting generated to it's location where it whould be.
```

Is there any prob with `SWFTools` installation or any other concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer... Firstly FlexPaper war file doesn't work properly for Linux for Windows it rocks... I made some code modification in FlexPaper\common\ view.jsp remove the following code

`else if(!conf.validParams(pdfFilePath, pdfdoc, pages)){`

```
 error += "Error:Incorrect file specified, please check your path.";
 }
```